# How to Query JSON Within A Database

Tags: sql, json, sqlite

I would like to query information from databases that were created in this format:

| index | label | key | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sneaker | UPC | {“size”: “value”, “color”: “value”, “location”: “shelf2”} |
| 2 | location | shelf2 | {“height”: “value”, “row”: “value”, “column”: “value”} |

Where a large portion of the data is in one cell stored in a json array. To make matters a bit tricky, the attributes in json aren’t in any particular order, and sometimes they reference other cells. Ie in the above example there is a “location” attribute which has more data in another row. Additionally sometimes the data cell is a multidimensional array where values are nested inside another json array.

I’m seeking to do certain query tasks like

- Find all locations that have a sneaker
- Or find all sneakers with a particular color etc

What’s the industry accepted solution on how to do this?

These are sqlite databases that I’m currently using [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to query. Definitely open to better solutions if they exist.

Comment: Trivial if it's using a version of sqlite built with the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension.

Comment: Though your database design could stand some normalization work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design that you have needs SQLite's [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html).

The tasks that you mention in your question can be accomplished with the use of functions like [`json_extract()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jex).

> Find all locations that have a sneaker

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.label = 'location'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM tablename t2
    WHERE t2.label = 'sneaker'
      AND json_extract(t2.data, '$.location') = t1.key
  )
```

> Find all sneakers with a particular color

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE label = 'sneaker'
  AND json_extract(data, '$.color') = 'blue'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=11955c80718c87db7af9d9b94114eb0c).

For more complicated tasks, such as getting values out of json arrays there are other functions like [`json_each()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach).